Monitoring of a directory and get notified for any new events like file creation in C++
I have a directory like data in root like /data, also i will have multiple directories like test, prod, staging inside data directory like below:
/data/prod/
/data/test/
/data/staging/
New files will be generated in sub directories like prod, test, staging dynamically.
I know we can use inotify API's to monitor the events in directories, but here i want to monitor al file creation events in the subdirectories of /data directory
how can i design this in C++? I want to monitor all the new files which are getting created in /data/prod, /data/test/, /data/staging/ directories

man inotify mentions how to handle this: Add watches recursively for all subdirectories (and when new subdirectories are created).

Design comment, I find that monitoring "directories for files" is a very very fragile way of doing inter process communication. If you are in control of the program producing the data AND of the program consuming the data (even if you use files) try to come up with some RPC communication protocol (e.g. use gRPC to send information that data is ready or just send the data using gRPC).

Apart mentioned inotify another fancy method is to use audit framework.
